# how to create a simple capacity expansion model while maximizing the revenue using PYOMO?

Tags: python, pyomo, capacity-planning

I have create a capacity expansion model using PYOMO, where there are 2 main generators **gen1** and **gen2** and one backup generator **lost_load**. The logic is pretty simple, gen1 and gen2 will run to fulfill the demand profile and they will get the money for that and there is some negative cost associated with gen1 and gen2 capacity. Here is the code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *


model = ConcreteModel()
np.random.seed(24)
load_profile = np.random.randint(90, 120, 24)
model.m_index = Set(initialize=list(range(len(load_profile))))

model.grid = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

#  Gen1 variable
model.gen1_cap = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.gen1_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

#  Gen2 variables
model.gen2_cap = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.gen2_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# Load profile
model.load_profile = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, load_profile)))

model.lost_load = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# Objective function
def revenue(model):
    total_revenue = sum(
        model.gen1_use[m] * 5.2 +
        model.gen2_use[m] * 6.1 +
        model.lost_load[m] * -100
        for m in model.m_index)

    total_fixed_cost = model.gen1_cap * -45 + model.gen2_cap * -50

    total_cost = total_revenue + total_fixed_cost
    return total_cost


model.obj = Objective(rule=revenue, sense=maximize)

# When i=0
def energy_balance1(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] <= model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] + model.lost_load[m]


model.energy_balance1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=energy_balance1)


def grid_limit(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] == model.load_profile[m]


model.grid_limit = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=grid_limit)


def max_gen1(model, m):
    eq = model.gen1_use[m] <= model.gen1_cap
    return eq


model.max_gen1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_gen1)


def max_gen2(model, m):
    eq = model.gen2_use[m] <= model.gen2_cap
    return eq


model.max_gen2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_gen2)


Solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')
Solver.options['LogFile'] = "gurobiLog"
# Solver.options['MIPGap'] = 0.50
print('\nConnecting to Gurobi Server...')
results = Solver.solve(model)

if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok):
    if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
        print("\n\n***Optimal solution found***")
        print('obj returned:', round(value(model.obj), 2))
    else:
        print("\n\n***No optimal solution found***")
        if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
            print("Infeasible solution")
            exit()
else:
    print("\n\n***Solver terminated abnormally***")
    exit()

grid_use = []
gen1 = []
gen2 = []
lost_load = []
load = []

for i in range(len(load_profile)):
    grid_use.append(value(model.grid[i]))
    gen1.append(value(model.gen1_use[i]))
    gen2.append(value(model.gen2_use[i]))
    lost_load.append(value(model.lost_load[i]))
    load.append(value(model.load_profile[i]))

print('gen1 capacity: ', value(model.gen1_cap))
print('gen2 capacity: ', value(model.gen2_cap))

pd.DataFrame({
    'Grid': grid_use,
    'Gen1': gen1,
    'Gen2': gen2,
    'Shortfall': lost_load,
    'Load': load
}).to_excel('capacity expansion.xlsx')
```

This model will work if :

```
def energy_balance1(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] == model.gen1_use[m] + model.gen2_use[m] + model.lost_load[m]


model.energy_balance1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=energy_balance1)
```

But if I set it to **(<=)** greater than equal to, it gives me an infeasible error. I want this condition because in actuality I want gen1 and gen2 to run at **100% capacity** at all 24 instances. After all, in the objective function, we can see the positive cost associated with **gen1_use** and **gen2_use**. So to maximize the revenue they should run at 100% capacity even if the load profile is fulfilled. Here is the output I am getting:

```
optimal gen1 capacity: 9MW
optimal gen2 capacity: 108MW
```

Although I want the dispatch something like this :
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are a couple issues going on here.  First, let's start with the logic...  Why run a model at all if the best thing to do is let the 2 generators run all the time.  You already know the answer....  run them both in every period.  This whole model can be reduced to an algebraic statement which would just be the value of running both all the time - sum of period shortages * cost of overflow gen

Comment: The actual scenario is a little different. In actuality, instead of the gen1 and gen2, I have solar and wind generators with their respective availability profiles. And yes you are right once we know the optimal size of gen1 and gen2 then to maximize the revenue we just have to run them for all instances but finding the optimal size is also a task here. 108MW and 9MW are coming from the model.

Comment: I think you should review some basic supply-demand models.  Typically, the story goes that there is some *cost* to supply (not a benefit) and then you minimize cost with the fundamental constraint that supply >= demand.  Part of that "supply" could be other supplying elements (like your overload generator) that have higher costs.

Comment: regarding you last comment:  Ok, then I would rust reduce the demand by whatever the solar/wind is doing to get a new demand profile.  So, then is it the case that you want the generators to run at full capacity (an unknown value/variable) only when needed to meet the remaining demand?

Comment: This is not investment optimisation , where we are trying to find the optimal dispatch. This is kind of RTC Model ( Round the clock) where there is a facility, which has solar and wind plants installed there and they will get money to supply energy and they have to pay penalty for the shortfall. I have added one more condition where i want to find what should the ideal size of generators along with RTC logic in order to maximise the revenue

Comment: And yes there is another component here in the actual scenario where we have Battery, which is getting charge and discharge from the solar and wind plant based on their availability. Yes you are right, in a simple RTC model we don't have to create a whole model in order to get the dispatch, we can just simply do these calculations on excel. But when battery is included in the system, it would become really difficult in excel in order to find ideal instance where we have to discharge or charge battery in order to maximise the revenue

Comment: I think your model will become non-linear if you want to have the capacity of the generator and when it is used both as variables because at some point, you are going to get to a space where if the cost of running is dependent on the capacity, you'll need to multiply variables.  Have you considered either fixing the capacity of the generator or assuming the running cost is not dependent on capacity?

Comment: Yes, but even in this basic model also you can see the model will work if in the energy_balance constraint i set the overall model energy generation equals to demand profile. But this gives infeasible error when i change the condition to model energy generation greater than or equal to demand profile. I don’t understand the reason behind it.

Comment: It's actually returning `unbounded` not infeasible, which makes sense.  You are giving credit for capacity and there is no upper bound on capacity

Comment: So if i add upper limit to generators then it should work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to get started.  I avoided making capacity a variable by including several distinct generator choices, which seems very reasonable.

This also incorporates a binary "use" variable, which I think you need from the described problem.

#### CODE:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

demand = [100, 200, 50, 22, 300]
solar_wind = [20, 100, 100, 0, 100]

net_demand = [d - s for (d, s) in zip(demand, solar_wind)]
print(net_demand)


# generator options...
gen_capacity = {'gen1': 25, 'gen2': 25, 'gen3': 50, 'gen4': 100}
running_cost = {'gen1': 12, 'gen2': 12, 'gen3': 30, 'gen4': 50}
shortage_cost = 100

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

### SETS
m.T = pyo.Set(initialize=range(len(demand)))     # time periods
m.G = pyo.Set(initialize=gen_capacity.keys())    # generators

### VARS
m.install = pyo.Var(m.G, domain=pyo.Binary)
m.use = pyo.Var(m.G, m.T, domain=pyo.Binary)
m.shortage = pyo.Var(m.T, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

### PARAMS
m.use_cost = pyo.Param(m.G, initialize=running_cost)
m.capacity = pyo.Param(m.G, initialize=gen_capacity)

### OBJ
m.cost = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(m.use[g, t] * m.use_cost[g] for g in m.G for t in m.T) +
                       sum(m.shortage[t] * shortage_cost for t in m.T),
                       sense=pyo.minimize)

### CONSTRAINTS

def demand(m, t):
    return sum(m.use[g, t] * m.capacity[g] for g in m.G) + m.shortage[t] >= net_demand[t]
m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(m.T, rule=demand, doc='meet demand')

def use_if_installed(m, g, t):
    return m.use[g, t] <= m.install[g]
m.C2 = pyo.Constraint(m.G, m.T, rule=use_if_installed, doc='can only use if installed')

m.C3 = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(m.install[g] for g in m.G) <= 2, doc='install at most 2 gens')

solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
result = solver.solve(m)
print(result)

m.display()
```

#### Output (a bit long)

```
[80, 100, -50, 22, 200]

Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 5210.0
  Upper bound: 5210.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 25
  Number of variables: 28
  Number of binary variables: 24
  Number of integer variables: 24
  Number of nonzeros: 24
  Sense: minimize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.0
  Wallclock time: 0.0
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.012147188186645508
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

Model unknown

  Variables:
    install : Size=4, Index=G
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        gen1 :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        gen2 :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        gen3 :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        gen4 :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    use : Size=20, Index=use_index
        Key         : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        ('gen1', 0) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen1', 1) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen1', 2) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen1', 3) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen1', 4) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen2', 0) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen2', 1) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen2', 2) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen2', 3) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen2', 4) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen3', 0) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen3', 1) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen3', 2) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen3', 3) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen3', 4) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen4', 0) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen4', 1) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen4', 2) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen4', 3) :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('gen4', 4) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    shortage : Size=5, Index=T
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
          1 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
          2 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
          3 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
          4 :     0 :  50.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals

  Objectives:
    cost : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True : 5210.0

  Constraints:
    C1 : Size=5
        Key : Lower : Body  : Upper
          0 :  80.0 : 100.0 :  None
          1 : 100.0 : 100.0 :  None
          2 : -50.0 :   0.0 :  None
          3 :  22.0 :  50.0 :  None
          4 : 200.0 : 200.0 :  None
    C2 : Size=20
        Key         : Lower : Body : Upper
        ('gen1', 0) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen1', 1) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen1', 2) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen1', 3) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen1', 4) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen2', 0) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen2', 1) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen2', 2) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen2', 3) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen2', 4) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen3', 0) :  None : -1.0 :   0.0
        ('gen3', 1) :  None : -1.0 :   0.0
        ('gen3', 2) :  None : -1.0 :   0.0
        ('gen3', 3) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen3', 4) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen4', 0) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen4', 1) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
        ('gen4', 2) :  None : -1.0 :   0.0
        ('gen4', 3) :  None : -1.0 :   0.0
        ('gen4', 4) :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
    C3 : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :  None :  2.0 :   2.0
```